# Получение данных из URL

Tags: php

Как получить значение login из вот такой URL "http://atittind.16mb.com/user/login" ))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Вынуть логин из $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

2) .htaccess (схематично):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)   /myscript.php?action=user&login=$1
```

Comment: Мне на phhp надо

Comment: См. пункт 1. В самом простом случае: $login = str_replace( '/user/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

Comment: Чёто не выходит тут логин

Comment: А нет добываеться только не bre а bre/

Comment: Я ж написал: "в самом простом случае". В исходном посте был URL без / в конце, вот для этого случая решение и приведено. Дальше будет вопрос как убрать / в конце, я правильно угадал?

Comment: Да вы прям Экстрасенс

Answer (score 1):

Например используя **.htaccess**

В файле **.htaccess** запишите следующее:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user/index.php?login=$1 [L]
```

И соответственно в файле **/user/index.php** получайте логин из переменной **$_GET['login']**

Comment: Мне на php надо)))))

Comment: это и есть php. 
Научитесь пользоваться файлом .htaccess